# Azure Artifacts maven publish stopped working this morning

Tags: java, azure, maven, gradle, artifacts

Publishing to Azure Artifacts using the maven-publish plugin in `gradle` has been working with no problem until this morning.  With no changes to the configuration, pipeline `.yml` files or the `build.gradle` files publishing stopped working with the following message

```
Could not PUT 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/jamarston/_packaging/jason0845/maven/v1/uk/co/jasonmarston/platform/framework/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/framework-0.0.1-20210519.094547-14.pom'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request - System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 1.    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32& bytesCount, Int32& charsCount)    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.GetChars(Int32 maxCharsCount)    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.SwitchEncoding(Encoding newEncoding)    at System.Xml.XmlTex (DevOps Activity ID: 21839509-D780-4424-BEE5-01AAC1A6D2E4)
```

Does anyone know the cause or have the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed. MSFT reverted back their changes.
https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/241774972